# Slow Response time load balancing through Cloud Service

Tags: azure, load-balancing

I have 4 x VM in a load balanced set, SSL port inbound with a probe path set on port 80.

Testing using jmeter hitting the web site and returning data.

Testing each of the VM's with the other three VM's out of the load balancer the average response time in milerseconds is from 45 - 55.

Testing each of the VM's with two, three or all four VM's in the load balancer the average response time in milerseconds is from 170 - 200 - 240.

Is this by deign or have I got something wrong

Thanks

Comment: Did you take into consideration the No. of threads when you are using more than 1 VM?

if you set No. of threads to 10 & use 4 VMs, it will generate 40 threads.

Comment: Hi I have done a few test with a few threads up to 30 threads ramping up every 1 second lopping 200 times same results each time

Comment: my suggestion is you run the same test from 4 VM's one at a time using your master. I doubt some VM's are have more latency than others.

Comment: Hi I did that the first time I run the same test for each VM on there own, each VM comes back the same around 45 - 55, then any combination of VM's 1,2 1,3 1,4 2,3 2,4 3,4 and so on the numbers range from 170 - 240, I am going to try a new test by spinning up a VM inside the DC and run jmeter from there see what number come out from that